# Display text when user clicks on any link

Tags: javascript

I want to display my licence agreement when the user clicks on any link on the page and prevent the link from taking the user anywhere. I need a way to make any click on the page show the code I want. Is there an easy way to do it? Like a scripts that tells the browser "when the user clicks something show this...".

Thanks a lot for any info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain javascript (but without any test for existing onclick handlers):

in the head add

```
<script>
var disclaimer="This link is not our responsibility - click ok to continue"
window.onload=function() {
  var links = document.links;
  for (var i=0, n=links.length;i<n;i++) {
    links[i].onclick=function() { return confirm(disclaimer);}
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The only problem I can see is that if you do anything else to the onLoad for the document, it will overwrite your script. Just a thought.

Comment: @Kyle - as I also mentioned in MY disclaimer ;) @Liso, you will need to [attachEvent / addEventListener](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=attachevent+addeventlistener+links) if you have any links that already has an onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    // show whatever you want
});
```